# Parentheses break Angular routing on page refresh

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am able to get to the following path from within the angular application (by clicking on the product link that has a routerLink):

```
{basePath}/product/trek-monda-slr-frameset-(h2-fit)-2016
```

However, once I refresh the page angular throws an error in the console and will not serve up the page:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'h2-fit'
```

My guess is that the angular router doesn't allow parentheses. But aren't parentheses valid characters in urls for most browsers?

Why isn't Angular allowing this?

Answer (score 5):

I know this isn't the most helpful, but it looks like there is an open bug on Angular's github that relates to this issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10280

If you have those parenthese hard coded then you could do like this comment says and replace them.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10280#issuecomment-279784004

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with refreshing or navigating backwards whilst using the following:

```
this.location.replaceState(`/portfolio/${this.activePortfolioId}/${this.activePortfolioName}/${user.id}`);
```

In the code above, if my portfolio name included "(*someText*)" I would run into this problem. The link that @Stout01 provided helped solve the problem for me.

Initial code:

```
this.router.navigate(['portfolio', portfolio.id, portfolio.name], {
  relativeTo: this.route
});
```

Fixed code:

```
var cleanPortfolioName = portfolio.name.replace(/[!'()*]/g,'');

this.router.navigate(['portfolio', portfolio.id, cleanPortfolioName], {
  relativeTo: this.route
});
```